# Using css inside a jsp maven project in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, resources

I am trying to add an external CSS file in a maven project that I am building in IntelliJ, but seemingly it doesn't work. Please help, what could I be missing out on?
Please note that when I use the styling internally it works fine (but I want to use other assets in my project).
I have included an image of the project structure below.

[image: code image]

Comment: Instead of linking an image to your code, please add it in your post. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS files are web resources it should be present in `src\main\webapp` or `src\main\resources\META-INF\resources` folder.

So, move your `css` folder to `src\main\webapp` then your CSS will work

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! I am now able to use my CSS